# Rotation of canvas not happening as per my expectation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my rectangle to rotate in place. But currently it is rotating as though there is one object at center and my object is revolving around it i.e much like what we see in solar system. I want my object to rotate in place not revolve around something. How can I do that?

This is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var context;
    var radian = 0.01;
    var w, h;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        w = document.width;
        h = document.height;
        var canvas = $('#canvas');
        context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
        canvas[0].width = w;
        canvas[0].height = h;
        setInterval(startAnim, 10);
    });

    function startAnim() {

        context.save();
        context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,0)';
        context.strokeRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        context.restore();
        context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,255,255)';
        context.fillRect(500, 400, 200, 200);
        radian += 0.01;
    }

</script>
```

**UPDATE:** Sorry I was experimenting before I posted and I forgot to add rotate function while posting here. This is the actual code:

```
function startAnim() {

        context.save();
        context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        context.translate(350, 300);
        context.rotate(radian);
        context.translate(-350, -300);

        context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,0)';
        context.strokeRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        context.restore();
        context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,255,255)';
        context.fillRect(500, 400, 200, 200);
        radian += 0.01;
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you applying the rotation code? Try adding context.rotate(radian) to the startAnim() function;

Comment: @Amaan Cheval: Extremely sorry. See my edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `translate(x, y)`, `rotate(r)`, and then draw your rectangle.

```
function startAnim() {
    context.save();
    context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    //^Shouldn't clearRect() be better here?

    //Draw translated, rotated rectangle at (250, 250)
    var x = 250;
    var y = 250;
    context.save();
    context.translate(x, y);
    context.rotate(radian);
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,0)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    context.restore();
    //Restore context (to reverse translation and rotation)

    context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,0)';
    context.strokeRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    context.restore();
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,255,255)';
    context.fillRect(500, 400, 200, 200);
    radian += 0.01;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zEJuh/) and [Simple jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nEAPm/) with one rotating rectangle

Answer (score 0):

You have to translate your context to the center of the rectangle before you rotate it:

```
context.translate(RECT_CENTER_X, RECT_CENTER_Y);
context.rotate(radian);
context.fillRect(-RECT_CENTER_X, -RECT_CENTER_Y, w, h);
```